# Add and remove style on click jquery

Tags: jquery

I created an SVG chart with different colors and connected each slice to a button. The first start of the chart is in grayscale then on the first click I want the grayscale filter removed and on the second click it is applied again. Here is what I have written:

grayscale filter

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#fox_box, #difetti_box, #polpa_box, #fior_bianchi_box, #lievito_due_box, #ortaggi_box, #frutta_polpa_bianca_box, #fiori_colorati_box, #floreali_box, #minerale_due_box, #affinamento_legno_box, #vegetale_box, #frutta_polpa_rossa_box, #agrumi_box, #pomacee_box, #drupacee_box, #frutti_tropicali_box, #botritizzato_box, #montagna_box, #bacche_rosse_box, #fortificato_box, #guaiava_box, #litchi_box, #minerale_box, #tabacco_box, #acidita_volatile_box, #malolattica_box, #lime_box, #solfiti_box, #chiodi_garofano_box, #pompelmo_box, #ribes_rosso_box, #tiglio_box, #lampone_box, #sottobosco_box, #gomma_box, #pesca_box, #melone_box, #scorza_arancia_box, #lievito_box, #siepe_box, #salsa_soia_box, #selvatico_box, #tappo_box, #cipolla_box, #erbe_essicate_box, #tostato_box, #fiori_arancio_box, #lavanda_box, #violetta_box, #limone_box, #ossidato_box, #peperone_box, #noce_moscata_box, #erbe_fresche_box, #pera_box, #finocchio_box, #albicocca_secca_box, #mora_box, #pomodoro_box, #erba_tagliata_box, #maderizzato_box, #prugna_secca_box, #gelsomino_box, #rosa_box, #te_nero_box, #fragola_box, #ciliegia_box, #ananas_box, #timo_box, #noci_box, #animale_box, #mais_box, #noce_cocco_box, #mela_verde_box, #prugna_box, #spezie_box, #caprifoglio_box, #acacia_box, #aneto_box, #fieno_box, #mela_box, #uva_spina_box, #foglie_box, #legno_box, #caramello_box, #idrocarburi_box, #cioccolato_box,#sandalo_box, #quercia_box, #muschio_box, #sherry_box, #vaniglia_box, #pino_box, #cuoio_box, #cavallo_box, #pepe_box, #pane_tostato_box, #cannella_bpx, #iodio_box, #burro_box, #caffe_box, #felce_box, #catrame_box, #fumo_box, #nocciola_box, #cedro_box, #cotognata_box, #incenso_box, #foglia_alloro_box, #miele_box, #fungo_box, #aceto_box, #eucalipto_box, #tartufo_box, #pietra_focaia_box, #mandorla_box, #salvia_box, #sapore_tappo_box, #madeira_box, #mollica_pane_box, #affinamento_vino_rosso_box, #liquirizia_box, #menta_box, #ribes_nera_box, #affinamento_vino_bianco_box, #solvente_smalto_unghie_box, #frutto_della_passione_box, #drupacee_box-2, #malolattica_due_box, #affinamento_vino_rosso_small_box")
      .css({ filter: "grayscale(100%)" });
});
```

This is the code that at the click removes the filter, precisely. I wish that at the second click the filter is restored.

```
jQuery('#btn-selvaticoooo').on("click", function() {
    jQuery('#difetti_box, #fox_box, #selvatico_box').removeAttr('style');
});
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Why not have a CSS class that applies the grayscale? Then you can just toggle the class on or off in the click event?

Comment: Surely you can create a class to use instead of that absurdly long list of IDs. Or maybe an "ends with" partial selector, like `$('[id$="_box"]')`.

Comment: Also, if you use `jQuery(function($) { ... });` for document.ready you can use dollar signs in your script.

Comment: But yes, simply toggling a class is a much simpler approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd refactor it a bit so that in your CSS you have something along the lines of:

```
#fox_box{
    filter: "grayscale(100%)";
}
#fox_box.noGray{
    filter: "grayscale(0%)";
}
```

Then you could do something like this in your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-selvaticoooo').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#fox_box').toggleClass('noGray');
    })
});
```

Or vice versa:

```
#fox_box{
    //non grayscale styling
}
#fox_box.grayscale{
    filter: "grayscale(100%)";
}
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-selvaticoooo').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#fox_box').toggleClass('grayscale');
    })
});
```

EDIT:

Based on the conversation in the comments, it's come to light that the requirements were a little bit more complex than a simple turning on and off of a class.

I'll simplify the example a little, but in essence there's some things that need to be kept in a set state while other elements change on the click:

In this case, you need a way of keeping track of what is active as well as simply turning bits on and off.

So let's say you have the following (simplified) HTML block:

```
<div class="thingsToToggle">
    <div id="thing1" class="grapefruit">
    </div>
    <div id="thing2" class="grapefruit">
    </div>
    <div id="thing3" class="grapefruit">
    </div>
    <div id="thing4" class="lemon">
    </div>
    <div id="thing5" class="lemon">
    </div>
    <div id="thing6" class="lemon">
    </div>
    <div id="thing7" class="melon">
    </div>
    <div id="thing8" class="melon lemon">
    </div>
    <div id="thing9" class="melon grapefruit">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="togglers">
    <button id="button1" class="grapefruit">
    </button>
    <button id="button2" class="lemon">
    </button>
    <button id="button3" class="melon">
    </button>
</div>
```

You could use something along the lines of this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button1').click(toggleFruit);
    $('#button2').click(toggleFruit);
    $('#button3').click(toggleFruit);

    function toggleFruit(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         
         var caller = $(e.target); //this gets the button that was clicked
         var grapefruitActive = $('button.grapefruit')
              .hasClass('active');
         var lemonActive = $('button.lemon')
              .hasClass('active');
         var melonActive = $('button.melon')
              .hasClass('active');

         if (caller.hasClass('lemon')) {
             //lemon button clicked
             $('.thingsToToggle .lemon')
                 .each(function(elem) {
                           //loop through lemon things to toggle and check they actually need toggling
                           if ($(elem).hasClass('grapefruit') && grapefruitActive) {
                               //Do nothing
                           }
                           else if ($(elem).hasClass('melon') && melonActive) { 
                               //Do nothing
                           }
                           else {
                                $(elem).toggleClass('grayscale');
                           }

                       });
         }
         else if (caller.hasClass('melon')) {
             //melon button clicked
             $('.thingsToToggle .melon')
                 .each(function(elem) {
                           //loop through melon things to toggle and check they actually need toggling
                           if ($(elem).hasClass('grapefruit') && grapefruitActive) {
                               //Do nothing
                           }
                           else if ($(elem).hasClass('lemon') && lemonActive) { 
                               //Do nothing
                           }
                           else {
                                $(elem).toggleClass('grayscale');
                           }

                       });
         }
         else {
             //grapfruit button clicked
             $('.thingsToToggle .grapefruit')
                 .each(function(elem) {
                           //loop through grapefruit things to toggle and check they actually need toggling
                           if ($(elem).hasClass('lemon') && lemonActive) {
                               //Do nothing
                           }
                           else if ($(elem).hasClass('melon') && melonActive) { 
                               //Do nothing
                           }
                           else {
                                $(elem).toggleClass('grayscale');
                           }

                       });
         }

         caller.toggleClass('active');

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!is a perfect solution. but I've realized that if I press more buttons the class that before was in gray scale is removed. instead it should be maintained. https://7c81b.wineqrcode.com/

Comment: I assume there's only one `#btn-selvaticoooo`?  If there's multiple buttons with the same ID it causes problems. I'm at work at the moment so I don't have time to wade through the developer tools pane to learn the structure of your site; but if you edit the relevant CSS into your question, I might be able to spot something.

Comment: there is only one button that on average turns on 3 id. The problem that the button next to it is selected, 2 should stay on and turn off the third one to turn on the corresponding one.

Comment: Right, so if you click the first button; you want 3 images grayed out and another button disabled?

Comment: 1) You should see the link I wrote above to understand. I have a wheel with 88 flavors so 88 buttons, which are divided into multiple categories. So if I give an example, the lemon and grapefruit flavoring are within the same categories which are, "white pulp fruit" and "citrus".

Comment: 2) If one clicks on the lemon button the two categories + the lemon part are activated in the chart, if one also presses grapefruit the two categories plus the two aromas must remain on. If one presses lemon again, the lemon segment must be switched off but the grapefruit must remain switched on. With your method it only works individually but if I start playing a mess happens. With my code I could keep what I needed on but I couldn't turn it off. Sorry if I was long I hope I am clear.

Comment: I'll add the last comment. I had at first created modifying the style because then this chart I have it downloaded and I saw that with the classes did not work. Thank you very much

Comment: If you see the edit, it should work a bit better.

Comment: Sorry I'm probably really stupid or getting lost on a glass of water. I created a jffiddle with the chart could you show me by doing just the first "white pulp fruit "frutta polpa bianca" "agrumi" "limone" "lime" "pompelmo"? https://jsfiddle.net/vencie/hbjkrw5g/14/